# Mysql Innodb count(*) performace

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `app_user` (
   `uid` int NOT NULL,
   `uname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `upwd` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
   UNIQUE KEY `uname` (`uname`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This is table sql i used to test, and i insert a million records into it. When i use the following sql to count row. It will cost 20 seconds to execute.

```
select count(*) from app_user;

+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | app_user | NULL       | index | NULL          | uid  | 4       | NULL | 996948 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

In this case, all records' uid are greater than 0. So i can use the sql like this to replace the first sql:

```
select count(*) from app_user where uid > 0; // In this case, all uid > 0

+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | app_user | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,uid   | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 498474 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
```

It just cost 500 milliseconds. Why does this happen?

I want to know why the second sql execute so fast.

Comment: Please include both execution plans.

Comment: How many of those million rows have `uid > 0`?

Comment: Test `select count({expression}) from app_user;` where `{expression}` is any indexed NOT NULL expression (for example, primary key).

Comment: @user207421 In this case, all uid > 0

Comment: @TheImpaler These execution plans have been put on

Comment: in first count, key didn't included and in second you included key so took less time and join type is range for that key or index scan which is always faster.

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/

Comment: @Akina in mysql `COUNT(*)` is identical to `COUNT(1)` (query parser rewrites it)

Comment: @zerkms `COUNT(indexed column)` may take the data from the index statistic.

Comment: I suspect caching. do you have the same results when you exec your 2 statements in opposite order?

Comment: @Akina `COUNT(1)` would take it from the PK statistic as well.

Comment: Please provide ``SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'app_user';`

Comment: `COUNT(x)` counts rows where `x IS NOT NULL`.  Usually, this unnecessarily slows down the query.

Comment: I see. Thank you